# java package <package> does not exist -> Java Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a file named "BibliotecaMusicalControle.java", that contains my main function, and when I try to compile it, I receive a message:

```
javac BibliotecaMusicalControle.java
```

Errors when trying to compile the code

[image]

I also have the folders "modelo" and "visao", which contains some files that I imported on the class I tried to compile

Folder modelo:

[image: Folder modelo]

Imports I made on BibliotecaMusical.java

[image]

So I wanted to know how I can compile the BibliotecaMusicalControle.java with the imports that I made.

Comment: I think you have to set the class path here.  You need to compile from the "top" of your project directory, and specify a full path to the file you are compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a directory structure like this:

```
mySrc
   controle
   modelo
   visao
```

You need to compile from the "top" of the directory structure, and you need to specify a full path to the file.  You also need the files in `modelo` and `visao` compiled so the .class files are available.

```
myScr> javac controle\BibliotecaMusicalControle.java
```

`\` is a file separator on Windows.  On Mac and Unix it's `/`.